# Creating Conditional Formatting with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create Conditional formatting that changes fill color based on the text in a cell, I keep getting "Argument not optional" 449 error on the bolded line.

```
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim formatRange As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet where the data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INSPECTION TEMPLATE")
    
    ' Find the last used row in column F
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set the range in column F
    Set rng = ws.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the range
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "" Then ' Check if cell is empty
            ' Set the formatRange for applying conditional formatting (columns I to AK) for the current row
            Set formatRange = ws.Range("I" & cell.Row & ":AK" & cell.Row)
            
            ' Clear existing conditional formatting rules in the format range
            formatRange.FormatConditions.Delete
            
            ' Apply conditional formatting rules based on cell value in the same row
            With formatRange
                ' Format "ACC" with white fill color
                **.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="ACC"**
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                
                ' Format "REJ" with red accent 2 fill color
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="REJ"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
                
                ' Format blanks with orange fill color
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlBlanks
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I want this to be automated but would it be easier to make it apply formatting to selected cells rather than using column F to get the range.

Comment: bolding did not show up in code block but the error is on line 29 -      
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="ACC"

Comment: try: `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="ACC", TextOperator:=xlContains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From using the macro recorder, it seems you're missing the `TextOperator`:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="ACC", TextOperator:=xlContains
```

Similarly:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="REJ", TextOperator:=xlContains
```

---

Also, I believe you want:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlBlanksCondition
```

instead of

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlBlanks
```